# Script to monitor space and send mail

Tags: perl

I want to write a perl script which monitors the space of multiple filesystem and if it exceeds the warning level, it should send a mail. EG: If the space is 98% and the free space is only 2%^ it should send a mail saying this path is full. Please delete some unwanted files from this path. Below is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Pass in command line parameter "--test" to perform an email test.
use strict;
use warnings;
use Filesys::DiskSpace;
# ---------------------------
# Configuration section
# ---------------------------
# default warning level
my $default_warning_level=10;
# email setup
my $to='admin@yourdomain.com';
my $from='webmaster@YOURDOMAIN.COM';
my $subject='Low Disk Space';
# folders to check
sub perform_checks {
    &check_free_space("/", 30);
    &check_free_space("/mnt/data");
    &check_free_space("/mnt/storage");
    &check_free_space("/mnt/backup", 20);
}
# ---------------------------
# Main script
# ---------------------------
my $out = "";
# Check free space for folder and add to email message if it is below warning level.
# Parameters:
#   folder_to_check - The path of the filesystem to check.
#   warning_level - If the free disk space percentage is below this level,
#                   an email is sent.  If this parameter is omitted, the
#                   default level will be used.
sub check_free_space {
    my ($dir, $warning_level) = @_;
    # set warning level to default if not specified
    if(!defined($warning_level)) {
        $warning_level = $default_warning_level;
    }
    # get df
    my ($fs_type, $fs_desc, $used, $avail, $fused, $favail) = df $dir;
    # calculate
    my $df_free = ($avail / ($avail + $used)) * 100.0;
    # compare
    if (($df_free < $warning_level) || (defined($ARGV[0]) && ($ARGV[0] eq "--test"))) {
        # append to email
        $out .= sprintf("WARNING Low Disk Space on $dir : %0.2f%% ()\n",$df_free);
    }
}
&perform_checks;
# check if there are warnings to email
if($out ne "") {
    # send email using UNIX/Linux sendmail
    open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");
    ## Mail Header
    print MAIL "To: $to\n";
    print MAIL "From: $from\n";
    print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n";
    ## Mail Body
    print MAIL $out;
}
close(MAIL);
```

But Im running the code in a citrix solaris environment. Im not able to install filesystem module. Could you please help me to write a code without using this module use Filesys::DiskSpace;.

Comment: Please don't repost your questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919360/how-to-write-perl-script-to-monitor-disk-space-and-send-an-email), you'll get into trouble if you do that. What have you tried already to replace that module that's not available? Don't wait for people to write your code for you.

Comment: Hi Mat,I deleted the post so i posted it again. Im not asking to write code for me. I just want to know is it possible to write code without using this module means can i write a code without using this module? If so juz give me a hint. This was my question.

Comment: Why can't you install the F:D module? I'd rather fix that problem, I think. If you can't install modules and don't need a portable or robust solution, you could use [backticks or other methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115809/when-is-the-right-time-and-the-wrong-time-to-use-backticks) to capture the output of a command-line command such as [`df`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?df).

Comment: if you don't like using external commands like df you can use the statfs system call. Because it is not available from perl directly you need to find out the syscall-number and arguments on your platform and then use the syscall function from perl. This is what Filesys::DiskSpace does and even if you cannot install it you might look into the source code of this module to find out the right way to call the statfs syscall on your platform.

Answer (score 4):

Sure it's possible, the simplest way would be to parse your system's `df` output. I'm not on Solaris so my `df` format might be slightly different, you might need to modify this for Solaris `df`.

```
## Since df gives %used, you can simply change your
## limit to be 90 instead of 10
my $default_warning_level=90;

## skipping the rest of the script

sub check_free_space {
    my ($dir, $warning_level) = @_;
    # set warning level to default if not specified
    if(!defined($warning_level)) {
        $warning_level = $default_warning_level;
    }
    # get df, on my system, this includes a usage percentage
    # which is what I guess you were calculating.
    my $res=`df $dir | tail -n 1`;
    my ($dev, $total, $used, $avail, $use_perc) = split(/\s+/,$res);

    # compare
    if (($df_free < $warning_level) || (defined($ARGV[0]) && ($ARGV[0] eq "--test"))) {
        # append to email
        $out .= sprintf("WARNING Low Disk Space on $dir : %0.2f%% ()\n",$avail);
    }
}
```

As a general note, unless you are using a *very* old version of Perl, don't use `&` with your subroutines unless you really know what you're doing. In most cases, the `&` is not needed and can often cause problems. See [here](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Perl/Subroutines-in-Perl/) for more info.